# Access li from ul ID inside jQuery plugin codes

Tags: jquery

Hi I am a little bit confused on jquery plugin documentation stated here:
http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/

My HTML markup:

```
    <ul id="slider1">
        <li><img src="images/slides/slide1.png" alt=""></li>
        <li><img src="images/slides/slide2.png" alt=""></li>
        <li><img src="images/slides/slide3.png" alt=""></li>
    </ul>
```

My jquery script:

```
    $('#slider1').jSlider();
```

on my jakeSlider.js script (Custom Plugin)

```
    (function($){
        $.fn.jSlider = function(){
          var $slidePos = 1;
          var $slideCount = $(this).find('li').length;
          var $next = $(this).find('a'); //FOR MY NEXT TEXT Hyperlink

          $(this).find('li:nth-child(' + $slidePos + ')').css('display', 'block');

          $($next).click(function(){
              $(this).find('li:nth-child(' + $slidePos + ')').fadeOut('slow');
              if($slidePos < $slideCount){
                  $slidePos += 1;
              }else{
                  $slidePos = 1;
              }
              $(this).find('li:nth-child(' + $slidePos + ')').fadeIn('slow');
             });
          };
    }(jQuery));
```

My Question:
How could I access or iterate the list index inside the ul?
I mean, I will access the 'li' inside along plugin scripts..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `ul` is your `this`, then you'd select its `li` elements like this:

```
$("li", this)
```

If you want to iterate across them, you could do something like:

```
$("li", this).each(function(){
    //Do stuff here.
});
```

**EDIT 1**

I found a few problems with your code that prevent it from working for me.

1. You're calling your plug-in with `$('#slider1').jakeSlider();`, but you've named your plug-in `jSlider`. But that's an easy fix.
2. Your sample HTML doesn't contain any `a` elements, so this line will never find anything: `var $next = $(this).find('a');`
3. Because of #2, your logic to handle clicks on your `$next` object will never fire.

Comment: Thank you Sir Tim. :)
I will try this one.
Cheers!

Comment: Hi Sir, I tried your suggestion on access li thru $("li", this) but it still doesnt work..

Here is my markup on testing for showing the li..

(function($){
 $.fn.jSlider = function(){
  $("li", this).css('display', 'block');
 };
}(jQuery));

Comment: I've gone through your code a big and found some major problems. Please see my edited answer.

Comment: Oops, I forgot to edit my post to replay .jakeSlider() into .jSlider()..
Accessing li still doesn't work in my new code in my jSlider.js plugin file:
(function($){ $.fn.jSlider = function(){ $("li", this).css('display', 'block'); }; }(jQuery));

Comment: If you want it to act like what's in your sample code, then try this: `$("li:nth-child(" + $slidePos + ")", this).css("display", "block");`. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/c4WNP/

Comment: Great thanks Sir Tim. I found out that I forgot to wrap my "$('#slider1').jSlider();" to "$(document).ready(function(){...});"

Thank you so much Sir. :)

Answer (score 0):

If the name of function is jSlider `$.fn.jSlider = function(){` so you must to use `$('#slider1').jSlider();`

Comment: Thanks mate but I already did that and that does not include on my concerns. :) Thanks anyways for answering.